# Как передать данные классу при переключении между вкладками при помощи Tab Controller?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

У меня есть Tab Controller, к нему в сториборде подключены другие контроллеры.

Например: есть контроллер Table View Controller, он подключён как отдельная вкладка. Для этого контроллера я создал класс, в котором переопределил методы.

У меня как минимум три вкладки однотипные, и мне было бы рациональнее использовать для них один класс, но просто устанавливать в этом классе в определённой переменной нужный режим.

В соответствии с этим режимом класс будет по своему себя вести. Суть в другом.

**Вопрос:** Как сделать так, чтобы при переключении вкладок в класс передавались необходимые данные?

Т.е. у меня будет 3 вкладки, одна для ленты новостей, другая для ленты личных постов, третья для лучших постов.

И вот у каждой из вкладок будет один и тот же класс, но когда пользователь будет нажимать на кнопку одной из вкладок, то при открытии надо как-то передать этому классу его роль.

Если не использовать Tab Controller, а к примеру открывать этот экран при помощи кнопки, то я могу задать segue и в prepareForSegue задать нужное значение для переменной. А вот с вкладками не знаю как быть.

Надеюсь понятно объяснил))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, проставить каждому tab bar item свой тэг. Тогда можно будет определить используемую вкладку:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let usedTabBar = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.selectedItem?.tag
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую чуть позже. Потом скажу как помогло.

Comment: Создал новый проект для теста. Всё работает. Большое спасибо за помощь!